# php Can't remove highlight after [username]

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a main admin page where I am able to greet the users by there username, 'Hello [username]', the username is highlighted. My problem is any tags after Hello [username] is also highlighted. How do I remove the highlights from the other tags?

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
if(Session::exists('home')) {
    echo '<p>' . Session::flash('home'). '</p>';
}
$user = new User(); //Current
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
?>

<?php include("layout/adminheader.php");?>

<?php include("layout/adminNav.php");?>

 <p>Hello, <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()-    >username);?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></p>

 <h6>TEST</h6>           
<?php   }   ?>
```

init.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
         'username' => 'secret',
         'password' => 'secret',
         'db' => 'db'
    ),
     'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
         'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
     'sessions' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
     )
 );
 spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
     require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
 });

 require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
 if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) &&      !Session::exists(Config::get('sessions/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=',    $hash));
   if($hashCheck->count()) {
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
 }
```

function page

```
public function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->isLoggedIn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgot to close  tag in your index.php file.

Look for the following line in index.php:

`<p>Hello, <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()-    >username);?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></p>`

And change it with
`<p>Hello, <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()-    >username);?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></a></p>`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I've been staring at it for hours. THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!!!